# how can i sort by using option value not option id value in listing page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, drop-downs, product-sorting

I have created a custom dropdown attribute and set in sort by dropdown listing page,

now currently magento 2 sort by using option id like "name="option[value][139][0]" but i want to sort using option value like "60".
Please refer screenshot so you can understand easily.

[image]

FRONT END - [image]

any have idea about this. thank you in advance.

Comment: The option ID is unique to that value so when you sort by that value it does technically sort by the value can you give any more information

Comment: @DavaGordon I want to filter in front end using option value like "60" but magento default functionality is using option id. I have attached the frontend screenshot.